# How should be a SPDX license name when extracting from another file content?

Tags: licensing, license-notice

Following the [SPDX simple license expressions](https://spdx.github.io/spdx-spec/v2.3/SPDX-license-expressions/#d3-simple-license-expressions) and the [License identifier field example](https://spdx.github.io/spdx-spec/v2.3/other-licensing-information-detected/#1013-examples), when creating a custom license that's not listed in [licenses list](https://spdx.org/licenses/) (including exception), I could use `LicenseRef-ACME`, where `ACME` is my company name, or even, my project name in a repository.

However, when having to extract a license text from a header, to distribute that custom license as a separated file, I'm not sure about:

- The license name that should be used (e.g. `LicenseRef-ProjectName`)
- The license file name that should be used (e.g. `LICENSE`)
- Custom fields in the license file to refer where I extract that text.

I read about [DocumentRef](https://spdx.github.io/spdx-spec/v2.3/file-information/), but I'm not sure if it's the case, and how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [reuse](https://pypi.org/project/reuse/) to validate my SPDXing and it's happy with the following:

1. Using `LicenseRef-ProjectName`. Unless your work is owned by a company and you're planning on using the same license for all your projects, in which case `LicenseRef-CompanyName` will indicate that to your customers.
2. I create `LICENSES/LicenseRef-ProjectName.txt` (`reuse` requires a copy of each license in the LICENSES folder).
3. No custom fields are required. The license file should be just the license text.

Then in a file using that license I use:

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: LicenseRef-ProjectName
# SPDX-FileCopyrightText: Copyright 2023 A. P. Hacker
```

Using a validator and simply following their guidelines can take some of the administrative burden off your shoulders.